# How to speech Korea,Thai,Russian,Japan in iSpeech of iOS?

Tags: ios

I want to do text to speech with Korean, Thai, Russian, Japanese with **iSpeech** in iOS.

Is that possible?

If it can be, how can I do that?

Any others SDK can speech above languages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

offcial ios siri now not working with this langs.
you can use google speach api or dragon speeach api.
http://www.nuance.com/for-developers/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.
`iSpeech` TTS is support to Korea,Russian,Japan.
but not support Thai language.

`iSpeech` is support to

- US English Female (default)

  US English Mal

  UK English Femal

  UK English Mal

  Australian English Femal

  US Spanish Femal

  US Spanish Mal

  Chinese Femal

  Chinese Mal

  Hong Kong Cantonese Femal

  Taiwan Chinese Femal

  Japanese Femal

  Japanese Mal

  Korean Femal

  Korean Mal

  Canadian English Femal

  Hungarian Femal

  Brazilian Portuguese Femal

  European Portuguese Femal

  European Portuguese Mal

  European Spanish Femal

  European Spanish Mal

  European Catalan Femal

  European Czech Femal

  European Danish Femal

  European Finnish Femal

  European French Femal

  European French Mal

  European Norwegian Femal

  European Dutch Femal

  European Polish Femal

  European Italian Femal

  European Italian Mal

  European Turkish Femal

  European Turkish Mal

  European German Femal

  European German Mal

  Russian Femal

  Russian Mal

  Swedish Femal

  Canadian French Femal

  Canadian French Mal

  Arabic Mal